# Count the number of words of each alphabet in a text file using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have just started with pySpark and I am trying to find the number of words for each alphabet from the text file. I am only considering the non-unique values. I could find the count of every word but couldn't proceed further.

```
data = sc.textFile("file.txt")
words = data.flatMap(lambda l : re.split(r'[^A-Za-z\t]+', l))
pairs = words.map(lambda w : (w, 1))
counts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda n1, n2 : n1+n2)
print(counts.top(10))
```

It is giving the output as `[('zwagger', 1), ('zounds', 2), ('zone', 1), ('zodiacs', 1), ('zodiac', 1), ('zo', 1), ('zir', 2), ('zipped', 1), ('zip', 1), ('zephyrs', 1)]`

But I am looking for the count of words for every alphabet. I tried iterating using for loop but I am getting `TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable` error. I tried applying groupBy

```
grouped = counts.groupBy(lambda x : x[0][0])
print(grouped.top(10))
```

but it is throwing `IndexError: string index out of range` which is weird. I am not sure how to proceed on this.

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: Replace `pairs = words.map(lambda w : (w, 1))` with `pairs = words.map(lambda w : (w[0] if w else w, 1))`